# setTimeout method,(swapping componets)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So I'm trying to create a setTimeoutmethod. So When someone presses one of the three buttons (drip,frenchpress, Aeropress). A setTimeoutmethod of .5 seconds will fire the event. swapping out{{ShowText}} to {{ShowText2}}Which is 'waiting for ' + this.order_type

```
  <div id="app">
    <barista-template></barista-template>
</div>

<!--template for customer-->
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
    <div>
        <div>{{showText}}</div>
        <button v-on:click="choose('drip')">Drip</button>
        <button v-on:click="choose('frenchpress')">French Press</button>
        <button v-on:click="choose('aeropress')">Aeropress</button>
        <div>{{showText2}}</div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="c-template">
    <div>
        <div>{{showText2}}</div>
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

______________JS_______________________________

```
    Vue.component("barista-template",{
    template: "#b-template",
    data: function () {
        return{
            order_type:"",
            order_value: "",
        }
    },
    computed: {
        showText () {
            if(this.order_type === '') return '';
            return 'One ' + this.order_type + ' that would be ' + this.order_value
        },
        methods: {
            swapComponent: function(component)
            {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.showText2('brewing')
                }, 1500);
                this.currentComponent = component;
            }
        }
        showText2 (){
            if(this.order_type === '') return '';
            return 'waiting for ' + this.order_type
        }
    },
    methods: {
        choose: function (order_type) {
            this.order_type = order_type;

            if (this.order_type == "drip") {
                this.order_value = "$10";
            }
            if (this.order_type == "frenchpress") {
                this.order_value = "$20";
            }
            if (this.order_type == "aeropress") {
                this.order_value = "$30";
            }
        }
    },
});
new Vue ({
    el:"#app",
    data:function () {
        return{
            showing:true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Right now you have both `showText` and `showText2` displaying. What do you mean by "swapping out"? Should only 1 of them display at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of behavior you're looking for? I added a `swapping` variable to indicate when swapping is taking place (meaning showText2 is displayed).

`swapComponent` sets `swapping` to `true`, then uses `setTimeout` to set it back to `false`. `choose` calls `swapComponent`.

```js
Vue.component("barista-template", {
  template: "#b-template",
  data: function() {
    return {
      order_type: "",
      order_value: "",
      swapping: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    showText() {
      if (this.order_type === '') return '';
      return 'One ' + this.order_type + ' that would be ' + this.order_value
    },
    showText2() {
      if (this.order_type === '') return '';
      return 'waiting for ' + this.order_type
    }
  },
  methods: {
    swapComponent: function() {
      this.swapping = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.swapping = false;
      }, 1500);
    },
    choose: function(order_type) {
      this.swapComponent();
      this.order_type = order_type;

      if (this.order_type == "drip") {
        this.order_value = "$10";
      }
      if (this.order_type == "frenchpress") {
        this.order_value = "$20";
      }
      if (this.order_type == "aeropress") {
        this.order_value = "$30";
      }
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      showing: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <barista-template></barista-template>
</div>

<!--template for customer-->
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
  <div>
    <div>{{swapping ? showText2 : showText}}</div>
    <button v-on:click="choose('drip')">Drip</button>
    <button v-on:click="choose('frenchpress')">French Press</button>
    <button v-on:click="choose('aeropress')">Aeropress</button>
  </div>
</script>
```